# Magento Admin Create Order Tax Module

Tags: admin, orders, tax, create

I can't seem to find which Mage model calculates the tax for an admin order.

I found the one that calculates it for a user order but not the one in the admin order create screen.

Anyone know which Model calculates the tax for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what block you're referring to specifically within the admin area but if you're talking about the tax totals block, if you look in

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals_Tax
```

you'll see that there is

```
public function getFullTaxInfo()
{
    /** @var $source Mage_Sales_Model_Order */
    $source = $this->getOrder();

    $taxClassAmount = array();
    if ($source instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order) {
        $taxClassAmount = Mage::helper('tax')->getCalculatedTaxes($source);
        if (empty($taxClassAmount)) {
            $rates = Mage::getModel('sales/order_tax')->getCollection()->loadByOrder($source)->toArray();
            $taxClassAmount =  Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->reproduceProcess($rates['items']);
        } else {
            $shippingTax    = Mage::helper('tax')->getShippingTax($source);
            $taxClassAmount = array_merge($shippingTax, $taxClassAmount);
        }
    }

    return $taxClassAmount;
}
```

Within that you can see that the Sales/Model/Order/Tax.php model and the Tax/Model/Calculation.php models are used as well as a couple of helpers.

Comment: Is this before the order is created in the Create New Order Section or after the order has been created? I am looking for before while you are still in the Create New Order Section of Magento Admin @user2045